# Python : select a specific line from text

Tags: python, python-2.7, linecache

i'm trying to make a code that :

- open a text file
- go to the lines that start with "Start"
- go to line 3 from the lines that start with "start" (previously selected)
- check if that line contain " contain" word

if yes = print " ok " :

```
str1 = "Start"

with open("C:...test.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    if str1 in line:
        if "contain" in line:
            print "OK"
        else:
            print "NOK"
```

i need to integrate the " 3rd line" condition

Comment: you can add a counter variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better memory usage you can use enumerate for line number tracking:

```
str1 = "Start"
fp = open("C:...test.txt")
check = 0
for i,line in enumerate(fp):
    if str1 in line:
        check = i
        continue
    if "contain" in line and (i == check + 3):
        print "OK"
    else:
        print "NOK"
```

Here i == check + 3 condition will check your 3rd line condition.

Comment: This has a disadvantage: Assume this:  line 1, 2 contain `Start`, line 4 has `contain`, this method would `miss`.

Comment: Worked for me with some modification + Advices from @zineb.l

Answer (score 0):

Might be small overhead, but if your file isn't too big, I'd just dump every line in a list L, then loop through that list - if row r starts with str1, you can just do L[r+3] and check if it contains 'contain'.

Comment: the file is around 1mb; and less memory/cache usage = the better the script is .

Answer (score 0):

Use two list to store the positions match your rule.

Then check out the position match your relative offset.

```
start_lines = []
contains_lines = []
with open("C:...test.txt") as inp:
    line_num = 0
    for line in inp:
        if line.startswith("start"):
            start_lines.append(line_num)

        if "contains" in line:
            contains_lines.append(line_num)

        line_num += 1

print [line_num for line_num in contains_lines if line_num - 3 in start_line]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mehdi ouahabi you motioned that "go to the line that start with ***Start***", so we check only the lines those start with "Start", and not those contain ***Start*** in the middle or at the end :

```
with open("test.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("Start"): #instead of "str1 in line" 
            if "contain" in line: print "OK"
            else: print "NOK"
```

***EDIT:***in this case you will check if a line start/ contain today's date

```
from datetime import date
with open("test.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
       #if str(date.today()) in line:#check if today's date exist in the line
       if line.startswith(str(date.today())): #check if the line start with today's dates
            if "contain" in line: print "OK"
            else: print "NOK"
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea ..
in case we want to check today's date in the start of the line .. it would be like " datetime.date.today() ", would this work ? i tried to use it with "if line in datetime..." but it didn't work

Comment: could you clarify more, you want to check the existence of some dates at the beginning of lines? or just today's date

Comment: @Mehdiouahabi i edit the response to check if a line start/ contain today's date

Comment: That helped me too much, Thank you Zineb.